# StyleGAN how to generate B image using A source image

Tags: generate, generative-adversarial-network

I am studying the StyleGAN. It is new for me, and I could not understand mix style of generating images.

In this image showed, that using A created B images. How can I do that, If I want to use A source image not from training data?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that example image, the A source images are *not* training data. They are generated images, of people who do not exist. The trained network (which is just the generator part) does not take any images as input, it only takes a random 512-dimensional vector (latent).

Thus, it is impossible to do what you ask using just the StyleGAN. You would need some way to reduce an input image to a latent vector, which is hard to do and isn't guaranteed to give reasonable results anyway.

The followup paper, StyleGAN2 (https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2) has an architecture where it is slightly easier to try to find a matching latent for an input image, and they even talk a bit about how to do it.

Comment: Thank you @Kristoffer Sjöö

Comment: @Kristoffer Sjöö I want to produce the exact same picture of a person just from their eyes. Do I also need to create a latent vector from the eye area?

Comment: Are you talking about reproducing a picture that was originally generated by StyleGAN? If not, what you talk about is fundamentally impossible (for _any_ approach), although a neural network could give a rough guess (which might be arbitrarily wrong).
If you wanted to try to make StyleGAN make a guess, you'd have to implement the system the OP tried to, except masking out everything but the eyes when computing the error. If StyleGAN was bad at the original problem, that would be even more true for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a source image not from training data, you need first to invert your image into one of the latent spaces of StyleGAN (Z-, W- or S-space). Inversion methods can typically be divided into three major groups: **gradient-based optimisation** of the latent code, **direct encoder-based mapping** onto the latent code, and **fine-tuning of weights** of the StyleGAN generator.

It is possible to create a non-existing facial image C that shares features of both source images A and B. Such Style-Mixing editing technique is possible by using latent representations of images A and B at different layers of the StyleGAN generator.

If a code is injected into early layers of the StyleGAN generator it affects rough facial features (e.g., face posture) while injection into later layers correspond to finer details (e.g., color of the skin).

Check Figure 3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.09102 for an explanatory picture and **Chapter 5 "GAN Inversion to Latent Spaces of StyleGAN"** for details.